# Ломаная и многоугольник, которые соединяют все точки обозначеные нажатием мыши

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Пользователь на рабочей области нажимает кнопку мыши несколько раз. Затем нажимает одну из кнопок. В зависимости от
нажатой кнопки должна нарисоваться или ломаная, соединяющая все точки обозначены
нажатием мышки, или многоугольник (замкнутый контур)

Пожалуйста помогите дописать, не знаю как дальше

Код:

```
#include "framework.h"
#include "task1.h"
#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100
 // Глобальные переменные:
 HINSTANCE hInst;                                // текущий экземпляр
 WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // текст строки заголовка
 WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // имя класса главного окна

// Отправить объявления функций, включенных в этот модуль кода:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                 _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                 _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                 _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
   UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
   UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);



// Инициализация глобальных строк
LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_MSP2, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

// Выполнить инициализацию приложения:
if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
{
    return FALSE;
}

HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_MSP2));

MSG msg;

// Цикл основного сообщения:
while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
{
    if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}

return (int) msg.wParam;
 }



 ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
   WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MSP2));
wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_MSP2);
wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
 }

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    hInst = hInstance;

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

if (!hWnd)
{
  return FALSE;
}

  ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
  UpdateWindow(hWnd);

return TRUE;}


//  ФУНКЦИЯ: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)

#define ID_BUTTONLine 1
#define ID_BUTTONPolygon 2
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc;
HBRUSH hBrush;
HGDIOBJ prev;
static int i = 0;
static POINT a[100];
static RECT rc;

switch (message) /* handle the messages */
{

case WM_SIZE:
    InvalidateRect(hWnd, &rc, true);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    break;

case WM_PAINT:
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 255, 0));
    prev = SelectObject(hdc, hBrush);
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        Ellipse(hdc, a[j].x, a[j].y, a[j].x + 10, a[j].y + 10);
    SelectObject(hdc, SelectObject(hdc, prev));

    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;

case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    if (i < 5) {
        a[i].x = LOWORD(lParam);
        a[i++].y = HIWORD(lParam);
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, &rc, true);
        UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    }
    break;

case WM_CREATE:
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
    CreateWindow(TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("Line"),
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
        10, 10, 200, 30,
        hWnd, (HMENU)ID_BUTTONLine, NULL, NULL);

    CreateWindow(TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("Polygon"),
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
        220, 10, 200, 30,
        hWnd, (HMENU)ID_BUTTONPolygon, NULL, NULL);
    break;
case WM_COMMAND:
   
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_BUTTONLine)
    {
     /////
    }
    break;

    if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_BUTTONPolygon)
    {
     /////
    }
    break;


case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0); 
    break;
default: 
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: "дописать" .. что? С чем конкретно сложности?

Comment: Что именно писать в условиях для кнопок "Line" и "Polygon" для того, чтобы они выполняли свои функции. 

if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_BUTTONLine)
    {
     /////ломаная, соединяющая точки
    }
    break;

    if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_BUTTONPolygon)
    {
     /////тоже соединяет точки - замкнутый контур, многоугольник 
    }
    break;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По нажатию кнопок можно устанавливать режим рисования и перерисовывать окно, а в обработчике WM_PAINT рисовать нужные линии, например так:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
  PAINTSTRUCT ps;
  HDC hdc;
  HBRUSH hBrush;
  HGDIOBJ prev;
  static int i = 0;
  static POINT a[100];
  static RECT rc;
  static int drawMode = 0;

  switch (message) /* handle the messages */
  {

  case WM_SIZE:
    InvalidateRect(hWnd, &rc, true);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    break;

  case WM_PAINT:
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 255, 0));
    prev = SelectObject(hdc, hBrush);
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
      Ellipse(hdc, a[j].x, a[j].y, a[j].x + 10, a[j].y + 10);
    SelectObject(hdc, SelectObject(hdc, prev));

    if (i >= 5) {
      if (0 != drawMode)
      {
        MoveToEx(hdc, a[0].x, a[0].y, NULL);
        for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
          LineTo(hdc, a[j].x, a[j].y);
        }

        if (2 == drawMode)
          LineTo(hdc, a[0].x, a[0].y);
      }
    }
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;

  case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    if (i < 5) {
      a[i].x = LOWORD(lParam);
      a[i++].y = HIWORD(lParam);
      InvalidateRect(hWnd, &rc, true);
      UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    }
    break;

  case WM_CREATE:
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
    CreateWindow(TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("Line"),
      WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
      10, 10, 200, 30,
      hWnd, (HMENU)ID_BUTTONLine, NULL, NULL);

    CreateWindow(TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("Polygon"),
      WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
      220, 10, 200, 30,
      hWnd, (HMENU)ID_BUTTONPolygon, NULL, NULL);
    break;
  case WM_COMMAND:

    if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_BUTTONLine)
    {
      drawMode = 1;
      InvalidateRect(hWnd, &rc, true);
      UpdateWindow(hWnd);
      break;
    }
    
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_BUTTONPolygon)
    {
      drawMode = 2;
      InvalidateRect(hWnd, &rc, true);
      UpdateWindow(hWnd);
      break;
    }
  case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
  default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

`MoveToEx` устанавливает текущую позицию, `LineTo` рисует линию от текущей позиции до указанных ей координат, и изменяет на них текущую позицию. Надо всего лишь установить текущую позицию в значение первой точки, а потом рисовать линии по всем остальным точкам.